# Inserting value into an array using key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have already fetched both key and value in array.how can I insert that value into another array in the same key position using that fetched key value.

Here my coding

```
$key=array_search($s_str,$opis_split);
//key value
$value=a;
//array value
$push=array_push($value,$key);
var_dump($push);
```

Comment: you should tag this with the language you're using

Comment: I wish there was some automatic feature in SO to identify the language for the question, which is not happening till now :D. So please write the language of the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert at nth key, use `array_splice($push, $n, 0, $value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$push[$key] = $value;
```

**Example**

```
<?php 
  $push = array('a', 'b', 'c'); 
  $key = 10;
  $value = 'z';
  $push[$key] = $value;
  var_dump($push);
?>
```

Would output:

```
array
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  2 => string 'c' (length=1)
  10 => string 'z' (length=1)
```

Is this not what you're trying to do?

Comment: No I need to insert a value at a key position which I have.For eg I have a key value 0 means,I have to insert a value at 0th key position of array.